# Implement Interface with List and get Value c#

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface named IConnector

Which has the following properties:

```
[OperationContract]
List<Details> RequestDetailsSchedule();

[OperationContract]
bool SetDetailsSchedule(List<Details> lstDetails);
```

I tried Implementing  by

```
public class Regulator: IConnector
public List<Details>RequestDetailsSchedule
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

How do i get the contents of the list?

Comment: Actually, there are no properties in your interface, there are 2 methods

Comment: How can I properly implement them?

Comment: What do you mean on "proper implementation"?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most basic way to implement to interface.

```
public class Regulator: IConnector
{
    public List<Details> RequestDetailsSchedule()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public bool SetDetailsSchedule(List<Details> lstDetails)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the list come from? A database? Anyway, just 'cause you're putting up an abstraction, I'd do it all the way, like this:

```
public interface IConnector {
    IEnumerable<Details> RequestDetailsSchedule();
    bool SetDetailsSchedule(IEnumerable<Details> details);
}
```